# Serializing Flux in Reactor

Tags: project-reactor

Is possible to serialize Reactor Flux. For example my Flux is in some state and is currently processing some event. And suddenly service is terminated. Current state of Flux is saved to database or to file. And then on restart of aplication I just take all Flux from that file/table and subscribe them to restart processing from last state. This is possible in reactor?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. `Flux` are not serializable and are closer to a chain of functions, they don't necessarily have a state<sup>[1]</sup> but describe what to do given an input (provided by an initial generating `Flux`)...

So in order to "restart" a `Flux`, you'd have to actually create a new one that gets fed the remaining input the original one would have received upon service termination.

Thus it would be more up to the source of your data to save the last emitted state and allow restarting a *new* Flux sequence from there.

---

<sup>**[1]**</sup> Although, depending on what operators you chained in, you could have it impact some external state. In that case things will get more complicated, as you'll have to also persist that state.